# How to remove unnecessary white space between title and table using kable in R Markdown to Beamer

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable

I want that the title of my table (blabla) goes close to the top of the table (no extra space). This question may be the same as from [Sara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139963/how-can-i-remove-the-white-blank-space-between-the-title-of-my-kable-table-and-t), but I provide a reproducible example. I have tried [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62309865/how-do-you-remove-white-space-between-title-and-table), but they don't work out.

````
---
title: "XYZ"
output: 
  beamer_presentation
---
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```
## 
```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:2,1:2],
      caption = "blabla",
      format = "latex")
```

\begin{table}

\caption{blabla}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|r|r}
\hline
  & mpg & cyl\\
\hline
Mazda RX4 & 21 & 6\\
\hline
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
````

Produces:

[image]

How can I remove the extra white space (in either case)?
It would better a proper solution, i.e., without manually changing the LaTeX code from kable...

Comment: The problem is that rmarkdown uses `\begin{tabular}[t]{l|r|r}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{l|r|r}` during the conversion to pdf

Comment: I see. However there are still a extra space (updated the question). To remove the extra space, would I need to use \vspace{-.5em} manually, or sth like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half of the white space is caused by rmarkdown using `\begin{tabular}[t]{l|r|r}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{l|r|r}`

The other half is the default spacing beamer uses below captions. You can control it via `\setlength\belowcaptionskip{7pt}`, but I would suggest to keep changes restricted to the `table` environment to not effect places where the caption is supposed to be below stuff like figures.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\caption{content...}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
c & d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{content...}
\end{figure}
text
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I used `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-8pt}}` in the `in_header` `includes` and all white space was vanished